# Typescript: Retrieve element type information from array type

Tags: typescript

Say I have some array type `T[]`, is it possible to extract the type `T` within another alias / interface? For example my (fake) ideal code would be as follows:

```
// for illustration only...

type ArrayElement<T[]> = T;

// then, ArrayElement<string[]> === string
```

If no, are there general type theory reasons for not allowing such an operator? If no again, I might suggest it be added.

Thanks!

Answer (score 196, accepted):

**Update: based on @jerico's answer below**

The following type alias will return the type of the elements in an array or tuple:

```
type ArrayElement<ArrayType extends readonly unknown[]> = 
  ArrayType extends readonly (infer ElementType)[] ? ElementType : never;
```

So these examples would work:

```
type A = ArrayElement<string[]>; // string
type B = ArrayElement<readonly string[]>; // string
type C = ArrayElement<[string, number]>; // string | number
type D = ArrayElement<["foo", "bar"]>; // "foo" | "bar"
type E = ArrayElement<(P | (Q | R))[]>; // P | Q | R

type Error1 = ArrayElement<{ name: string }>; 
//                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
// Error: Type '{ name: string; }' does not satisfy the constraint 'readonly unknown[]'.
```

**Explanation**

The type guard (the bit in the angle brackets) `ArrayType extends readonly unknown[]` says that we expect the type parameter `ArrayType` to be at least a readonly array (it also accepts a mutable array) so that we can look at its element type.

This prevents passing in a non-array value, as in the final example, which prevents `ArrayElement` ever returning `never`.

Note that `readonly unknown[]` is syntax added in TypeScript 3.4; for earlier versions use `ReadonlyArray<unknown>`.

On the right-hand side, the conditional expression asks the compiler to fill in the value of `ElementType` in the pattern `readonly ElementType[]` and return `ElementType` if it can, or `never` if it can't.

Since the type guard at the beginning means we will only ever be passed a value which matches this pattern, it's guaranteed always to match and never to return `never`.

**Previous answer**

```
type ArrayElement<ArrayType extends readonly unknown[]> = ArrayType[number];
```

Comment: This implementation infers the element type from the array type, while the accepted answer infers the type of the first element in the array. I just thought it was more elegant, but since the array is guaranteed (by its type definition) to only contain elements of the same type, there's no technical advantage to using this solution.

Comment: Typescript supports indexed based array element types such as: `[number,string]`. So this answer has some advantages as `ArrayElement<[number,string]> -> number | string`

Comment: this should no longer be the accepted answer, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41253310/typescript-retrieve-element-type-information-from-array-type#comment113940662_57447842)

Comment: I agree with @feihcsim. My answer may have issues if the `--noUncheckedIndexedAccess` flag is enabled, whereas @jerico's answer wouldn't. That'd be enough of a reason for me to choose that answer over my one, which is a little sad since `ArrayType[number]` is much easier to read, especially for beginners.

Comment: @feihcsim I'm pretty sure this answer did not need to change and the original answer (`ArrayType[number]`) still works fine, even with `--noUncheckedIndexedAccess` enabled.  That flag does not affect these type-level operations.

Answer (score 122):

Since 2.1, typescript supports [ ] operator for types. The official name is [indexed access types, also called lookup types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#keyof-and-lookup-types), and it works like this:

```
type A = {a: string, b: number} [];

type AElement = A[0];

let e: AElement = {x: 0}; //error TS2322: Type '{ x: number; }' is not 
                       //assignable to type '{ a: string; b: number; }'
```

Comment: What's happen when a be nullable ?

Comment: Same or similar error because type `{ x: number; }` is still not assignment-compatible with the type of array element

Comment: It's also possible to do `YourArray[number]` which I think is more general than `YourArray[0]`

Answer (score 93):

Another alternative:

```
type ArrayElement<A> = A extends readonly (infer T)[] ? T : never
```

Comment: this is actually the only one true "correct" answer. i believe it's for this reason that [the TypeScript team is going to be releasing a `--noUncheckedIndexedAccess` flag](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-1-beta/#no-unchecked-indexed-access)

Comment: it's also the only working way for complex types such as `P[] | (Q | R)[]`

Answer (score 57):

This can be achieved pretty easily by writting index type in brackets:

```
type ArrayElementType = ArrayType[number];
```

**Update**

As a comment below suggests, to create a generic array element type:

```
type ArrayElementType<ArrayType extends Array> = ArrayType[number];
```

*P.S. `number` is not a value but a type.*

Comment: Or as a generic type: `type ArrayElementType<A extends Array> = A[number]`

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: The generic version doesn't work for me. TypeScript gives error: `Generic type 'Array<T>' requires 1 type argument(s).`

Comment: Managed to make it work with the following code: `type ArrayElementType<ArrayType extends Array<T>, T = any> = ArrayType[number];` But it's no more a nice short answer. Plus it has this extra type parameter `T`.

Answer (score 6):

Another option:

```
type Flatten<Type> = Type extends Array<infer Item> ? Item : Type;
```

You can find more about `infer` at:
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#inferring-within-conditional-types:

Answer (score 5):

The utility-type library has a type for that https://github.com/piotrwitek/utility-types#valuestypet (along with many others)

For example

```
import { ValuesType } from 'utility-types';

type NumberArray = number[];
// Expect: number
type NumberItems = ValuesType<NumberArray>;
```

Comment: How does one use it? Can you edit your post and give an example?

Answer (score 3):

Using conditional types this snippet flattens array types to their element types, or leaves them alone otherwise

```
type Flatten<T> = T extends any[] ? T[number] : T;
```

Implementing the snippet above `type Str` below will have a type of `string`

```
// Extracts out the element type.
type Str = Flatten<string[]>;
```

and `type Num` below will remain it's original type `number`

```
// Leaves the type alone.
type Num = Flatten<number>;
```

In summary when `Flatten` is given an array type, it uses an indexed access with `number` to fetch out `string[]`’s element type. Otherwise, it just returns the type it was given. This example was sourced from the Typescriptlang handbook on [conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html)

Comment: FWIW, this is working well in my case... the first example of an array type.

Answer (score 1):

Based on @will-madem's answer, I've done a couple of tweaks:

- The generic might be an array, or not: `T` or `T[]`
- It will remove multiple "levels" of array: `T[][][]` => `T`

[Full example here.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAggTnAhiAogGwgWwgO2AHgFlkAjCeJEAFXAgD4oBeKAKCimJDIuRsiggAPYLgAmAZyhwIiUQHscaEFAAUASxwAzCHCjosuYHwgBKANoBdNuygB+VdZs392PMYHCxkgK44A1jhyAO44lo5OEfY8qBiuBC6GxnThETYAXHqxibThJuEZnNwIvLQA3CwsoPwAYnJyTLDFMQZ4+OLAcBoA5pZ05VXQAEKIuszRCa3tnThdfZW0UMMAXg3jWZMd3ZbbFr3lLADGCu1QmnUZtfXMAORnctflRzgnJCMZw6NQ169wD4fHwCgryW70QKxuwIeQA)

```js
type ArrayElement<MaybeArrayType> = 
  MaybeArrayType extends readonly (infer ElementType)[]
    ? (
        ElementType extends unknown[]
            ? ArrayElement<ElementType>
            : ElementType
    )
    : MaybeArrayType;
```

Answer (score 0):

The [type-fest](https://github.com/sindresorhus/type-fest) library calls this an `IterableElement<T>` and it allows to extract the element type of any `Iterable` or `AsyncIterable`, including arrays and generators:

```
type MyArray = Array<number>;
type MyArrayElements = IterableElement<MyArray>;
```

Answer (score -2):

I got the shortest answer.

```
type A = Array<string>;
type B = A[0]; // string
```

https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=2&ssc=15&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8sBOSCGIA8BnYSCWAdgOYB8A3AFCiRQBCCsA2gAwC6ZQA

Comment: The point of the question was to infer `string` from its contents, without knowing what it is.