# What is the effect of (typeof arr1)[number]? Is there any other usage? Such as [string] or [union type]?

Tags: typescript

What is the effect of [number]? Is there any other usage? Such as [string] or [union type]?
I want to find the relevant handbook

```
const paths = ['index', 'demo'] as const;
export type RoutePath = (typeof paths)[number];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[number]` refers to an [Indexed Type](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#index-types-and-index-signatures), from the Advanced Types page of the handbook.

> An index signature parameter type must be ‘string’ or ‘number’. If you have a type with a string index signature, `keyof T` will be `string | number` (and not just `string`, since in JavaScript you can access an object property either by using strings (`object['42']`) or numbers (`object[42]`)).

`paths` is an array of strings, which could also be described this way:

```js
interface ArrayOfStrings {
  [index: number]: string;
}
```

Therefore, `(typeof paths)` is a `string[]`, so `(typeof paths)[number]` is a `string`. This syntax also works if your object is an array-like object, or has string properties in addition to numeric indexes.

See also: [Typescript: Retrieve element type information from array type](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41253310/1426891)