# Typescript: How do I reference a subtype of an Array definition?

Tags: typescript

So I'm generating types from a GraphQL schema using `graphql-codegen` and I get things like:

```
export type CustomersQuery = (
  { __typename?: 'Query' }
  & { customers?: Maybe<(
    { __typename?: 'CustomerPaginator' }
    & { data: Array<(
      { __typename?: 'Customer' }
      & Pick<Customer, 'id' | 'uuid' | 'name' | 'status' | 'createdAt' | 'accountNumber'>
    )> }
  )> }
);
```

I have a React component that gets supplied the contents of one `customers.data` array element as a prop. I figure I should be specifying that requirement in it's interface right? Currently I have:

```
interface MyComponentProps {
  customer?: Partial<Customer>
}
```

How can I be more specific and reference that `Pick` from `type CustomersQuery` in my `interface`?

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Typescript: Retrieve element type information from array type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41253310/typescript-retrieve-element-type-information-from-array-type)

Comment: Also is this what you want: `Partial<Omit<NonNullable<CustomersQuery['customers']>['data'][number], '__typename'>>`

Comment: Ah that is! Thanks very much ideed!