# Typescript parameters to keys and values from an object

Tags: javascript, typescript

Example

```
const food = {
  fruit: ['apples', 'oranges'],
  meat: ['chicken', 'pig']
}

function makeFood(ingredient, category) {
 switch(true) {
   case category === 'fruit' && ingredient === 'apples' {
    // do something
   }
   case category === 'fruit' && ingredient === 'oranges' {
    // do something
   }
   case category === 'meat' && ingredient === 'chicken' {
    // do something
   }
   case category === 'meat' && ingredient === 'pig' {
    // do something
   }
 }
}
```

what's the best way to type category is a key of food and ingredient is a value?

Currently I'm doing

```
function(ingredient, keyof typeof category) {
```

would love to keep the relation between the two. So TS will know the ingredient type based in the category value.

Comment: Can you please provide a more complete example?

Comment: What's `category`? How do `ingredient` and `category` relate to `food`?

Comment: I'll update the question right away

Comment: Not sure what exactly you want, but something like `function f<T extends keyof typeof food>(ingredient: (typeof food)[T][number], category: T) {`? Note, that unless you add `as const` to the arrays in `food`, they are just `string[]`. Also note, that `[number]` may be a bit quick&dirty, there are [alternatives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41253310/typescript-retrieve-element-type-information-from-array-type).

Comment: @Norfeldt wasn't my down vote

Comment: Sorry about that @TitianCernicova-Dragomir

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You use typescript [Generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html). In this you wanted `category` to be generic parameter, which ingredient can then use.

You'll need to use `as const` (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66993264/what-does-the-as-const-mean-in-typescript-and-what-is-its-use-case)) on your source object to make sure it's specific string are part of its type.

```
const food = {
  fruit: ['apples', 'oranges'],
  meat: ['chicken', 'pig']
} as const // important to add "as const" here

function makeFood<
  K extends keyof typeof food // Generic parameter
>(
  ingredient: typeof food[K][number], // use K to lookup types for ingredient
  category: K // provide the key to to use here as K
) {
 switch(true) {
   case category === 'fruit' && ingredient === 'apples': {
    // do something
   }
   case category === 'fruit' && ingredient === 'oranges': {
    // do something
   }
   case category === 'meat' && ingredient === 'chicken': {
    // do something
   }
   case category === 'meat' && ingredient === 'pig': {
    // do something
   }
 }
}

makeFood('apples', 'fruit')
makeFood('pig', 'fruit') // type error
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=29&ssc=39&pln=28&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZiEATGBeGBvAUDeAnAVwEsoAuGAbQHIBDABzoBsBTCKgGhipDxrAHNWVALrscMALbMaZSlWAALIsADWzMBy50i-EVgC+MGhBihIULFjgEwwKEXCSaagGKIkAHnEBpGMwAeUOpIJmoAniBwMFBhdMyR8O5YAHwAFOJEAnjMSETqsjFxCQjIFN7CFGAEEgBGzHii4sAyzPw8YeTeWACUmDgQAO4kiqlQhMy92LimxswzQW14YWio6FRwhCRUMABkOzCZ-Nm5+Str9ExC5FPTAPS3MEggMBAgUlBKAuIw+t-NEHNmgt2mcuBtiFBtnsDlkcnkwLBVmseHxBGxrt8YPdHs9Xu9Pvxvr9pv9AS1FsskVwpDIoftDsd4YjVlxFMo1BoMdMsQ8ni83swPociX9ZvNWiCqVQaZDdvTYScEaCqNpdFy7rzcQKhV9psTfr8sBJnMw3MhUrQGCw2Jx1ptId0jSazUgLarNHaIVRetjCnN6ngeEA)

Comment: Also cool to note that it will prevent you from using typos in the switch.

Comment: Thank you very much for such a quick answer

Comment: An alternative without generics is `function makeFood(ingredient: typeof food[typeof category][number], category: keyof typeof food)`

Comment: And I keep thinking there must be a way to use `infer` so the compiler can infer that in the first `case` clause, ingredient could only be `'apples'|'oranges'`

Comment: @JuanMendes your suggestion without generics is event better since it keeps the relation between the types when autocompleting in vscode. If you post it as an answer I'll give it a vote.

Comment: @Norfeldt Can you explain what worked better?  I couldn't find a difference. Since you have this understanding, it may be better for you to post that answer yourself, then I can learn from it.

Comment: I see now that it works the same in Playground - it just seemed to me that it was working differently in vscode, but I doubt that. Anyway I like your suggestion very much and thank you for that 