# Access type of the element of an array

Tags: typescript

I would like to access the type of the element of an array instead of rewriting the type

For example

```js
interface Person{
firstname: string,
lastname: string
phonenumbers: Array<{prefix:number, phonenumber: number}>
}
```

I would like to access the type of `phonenumbers` element without redefining it and with a generic way. It could be like this

```js
type PhoneNumber = ArrayElementType<Person["phonenumbers"]>
```

I tried the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41253310/typescript-retrieve-element-type-information-from-array-type), but it does not work for me.

Comment: Why not define a type `PhoneNumber` and make `phonenumbers: Array<PhoneNumber>`?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this directly:

```ts
interface PhoneNumber {
    prefix:number; 
    phonenumber: number;
}

interface Person{
    firstname: string,
    lastname: string
    phonenumbers: PhoneNumber[]
}

type ShouldBeNumber = Person['phonenumbers'][number]['phonenumber']
```

or you can do it generically although it's more complicated:

```ts
type ExtractMember<T extends {}, K extends keyof T> = T[K]
type ExtractObjectArrayMember<T, K> = T extends (infer R)[]
  ? K extends keyof R 
    ? ExtractMember<R, K>
    : never
  : never;

type AlsoNumber = ExtractObjectArrayMember<Person['phonenumbers'], 'phonenumber'>
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=17&ssc=82&pln=1&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgAoAsD2IIDkCuAtgEbTIDeAsAFDJ3IAOUEMwAHgFwhGlQDcyGvUZYc3EtA7JxvPjQC+NGqEixEKVNADO2KrXqsoWsCDiEIU41FABzADRD6AGzjHT5y2Gsgbjug1EIGW0pAEEoKDgATwAeDGw8HmgAPgUlajAohhQAZSx8JwATACFEiShkAF40bWwAbQByAITgowaAXTrWzqbA1o70zOzkAFE2L0QwAFkIcpiAFWQIcaDCrQp5O2QAaSWVkDXkAGsIKMwYZHnkqsu67faaIZQxiYQwAHliACsIN-DIqIzObzLbba7VRbLSAHdYAClAMDIACUAJR1drIAD8Oz20MOJzOFyRWNG40ibyBvBiSNB1ykOAAbmR6RAmVBBlkUKEnDoCOUbi9yR9vr8wP9opToHFaiBGs0xEk2u0tr0WoqGqlqEA)