# How to get the array object type in typescript

Tags: typescript

For example
I have an array data

```js
const Arr = [
  {
    name: 'setTitle',
    method: (title: string) => {
      return title;
    }
  },
  {
    name: 'getName',
    method: () => {
      return 'hello world';
    }
  }
];
```

I want get type like this

```
type Result = {
  setTitle: (title: string) => string;
  getName: () => string
}
```

How to derive it directly from typescript?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Typescript: Retrieve element type information from array type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41253310/typescript-retrieve-element-type-information-from-array-type)

Answer (score 1):

You would have to use `as const` when declaring `Arr` to preserve the narrowed type information of the `name` properties.

```
const Arr = [
  {
    name: 'setTitle',
    method: (title: string) => {
      return title;
    }
  },
  {
    name: 'getName',
    method: () => {
      return 'hello world';
    }
  }
] as const;
```

Now the `Result` type can be constructed like this:

```
type Arr = typeof Arr

type Result = {
  -readonly [K in Arr[number] as K["name"]]: K["method"]
}

// type Result = {
//     setTitle: (title: string) => string;
//     getName: () => string;
// }
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=20&ssc=2&pln=16&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBAggJwTAvDA2gKBjA3tnGMAQwFsBTALhgHIJyoAVASygBtyaAaAnCqABYgAJtQAUUVh2rQEzMAHMAlKgB8eXoQQMArgjAxJ7cgG5NAXwLmeOfISJkqtBQwByj7pv5DRMMSpR1O3sYbSg9AxoBcjY2EBgAdxAENmEaM3tLHEsAXRhiCBhQSCgzTCgATwAHcngkVENq8hAAMzqETHKmmAAlcggdNlg0YIBabWJhcDYKjABpGHl29DAdUgAjcgQ8gpg59AAiEgoDnJzqfYPvEVPMS0wAegfGmt7+weGNJ5D6JiknCT-GRQOSKALqWTyBRmb72FxQdwUcTgmCQxQw57mIA)