# Typescript - intersection operator with union type

Tags: typescript

Here's a design of an event emitter:

```
type EventMap = Record<string, any>;

type EventKey<T extends EventMap> = string & keyof T;
type EventReceiver<T> = (params: T) => void;

interface Emitter<T extends EventMap> {
  on<K extends EventKey<T>>
    (eventKey: K, fn: EventReceiver<T[K]>): void;
  emit<K extends EventKey<T>>
    (eventKey: K, params: T[K]): void;
}

// example usage
const emitter = eventEmitter<{
  data: Buffer | string;
  end: undefined;
}>();

// OK!
emitter.on('data', (x: string) => {});

// Error! 'string' is not assignable to 'number'
emitter.on('data', (x: number) => {});
```

The design works but two things I don't understand:

1. `EventKey`: why does it need to add a `string &` here?
2. Why do we need generics `K` with `on` and `emit` methods, can't the type for `eventKey` param simply be `keyof T`?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> EventKey: why does it need to add a string & here?

The intersection `string & ...` is used to make sure that only keys that are actually of type `string` can be used to define the `EventKey` type.

Even though `EventMap` is defined as `Record<string,any>` you can still assign an object with non-string properties to it:

```
const a: EventMap = {
  foo: 'bar',
  100: 'baz', // whoops, number property
}
```

Why? Because objects can have [excess properties](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#excess-property-checks).

So in such a case, `string & keyof T` would result to `never` for rogue properties that are not of type `string`.

> Can't the type for eventKey param simply be keyof T?

This is to allow keys defined as union types, which do extend `string` (See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57342018/extending-a-string-in-typescript)):

```
type EnumK = 'alpha' | 'beta'
type MyObject = {[P in EnumK]: string }

const obj: SomeObj = {
  alpha: 'foo',
  beta: 'bar'
}
```

Here the type of `obj`'s keys is an *extension* of `string`, namely the union between the string literal types `alpha` and `beta`. So by using `K extends ...` you capture this relation and ensure type safety in type indexing `T[K]`.