# How can an interface extend the type string?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I don't understand the following code example:

```
IdType extends string
```

IdType consists out of several value types, how can it extend a string?

```
   const Select = <IdType extends string>(props: {
      options: Array<{
        id: IdType;
        name: string;
      }>;
      selectedItemId?: IdType;
      onSelect: (id: IdType) => void;
    }) => (
      <select
        value={props.selectedItemId ?? ''}
        onChange={e => props.onSelect(e.target.value as IdType)}
      >
        {props.options.map(option => (
          <option key={option.id} value={option.id}>
            {option.name}
          </option>
        ))}
      </

select>
);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Extending a string in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57342018/extending-a-string-in-typescript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This makes sure this won't compile because you're not accepting any string, but one very specific string:

```
Select<'mystring'>({
  options: [{
    id: 'invalid', // fails
    name: 'name'
  }],
  selectedItemId: 'mystring', // OK
  onSelect: (id: string) => {}
});
```