# How to define properties in a Typescript interface with dynamic elements in the key name?

Tags: typescript, mapped-types

I have an object that can have an `n` number of properties, each one the same but with their `n` value in the name.

Example:

```ts
const obj = {
  'data-element-0': 'something',
  'data-element-1': 'something else',
  'data-element-2': 'something as well',
  'data-element-3': 'something to feel included',
};
```

Is there any way to define this interface with more specificity than just using

```ts
interface Obj {
  [key: string]: string;
}
```

Comment: What are your constraints exactly?  Do the indices need to start from `0`?  Do they need to be whole numbers?  Do they need to be consecutive whole numbers with no gaps?  Etc etc.

Comment: If they need to be consecutive with no gaps, is there a reasonable maximum `n` or is it potentially unbounded?

Comment: Why dont you use an `string[]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do smth like that:

```js
type Key = `data-element-${1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|0}`

const obj:Record<Key, string> = {
    'data-element-0': 'something',
    'data-element-1': 'something else',
    'data-element-2': 'something as well',
    'data-element-3': 'something to feel included',
    'data-element-yu': 'something to feel included', // error
};
```

**UPDATE**
I have also make helpers fot double numbers, from: 0-99:

```js
type NonZeroDigit = '0' | '1' | '2' | '3' | '4' | '5' | '6' | '7' | '8' | '9'

type NumberHelper = {
  [P in NonZeroDigit]: {
    [Z in NonZeroDigit]: `${P}${Z}`
  }
}

type NestedValues<T extends Record<string, Record<string, string>>> = {
  [P in keyof T]: P extends string ? Values<T[P]> : never
}
type Values<T> = T[keyof T]

type RemoveTrailingZero<T extends string> = T extends `${infer Fst}${infer Snd}` ? Fst extends `0` ? `${Snd}` : `${Fst}${Snd}` : never;

type Numbers_99 = RemoveTrailingZero<Values<NestedValues<NumberHelper>>>
```

**UPDATE**

Here you have an util for generating number range from 0 to 99999

```js
type Values<T> = T[keyof T]

type LiteralDigits = 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9
type NumberString<T extends number> = `${T}`

type AppendDigit<T extends number | string> = `${T}${LiteralDigits}`

type MakeSet<T extends number> = {
    [P in T]: AppendDigit<P>
}

type RemoveTrailingZero<T extends string> = T extends `${infer Fst}${infer Rest}` ? Fst extends `0` ? RemoveTrailingZero<`${Rest}`> : `${Fst}${Rest}` : never;

type From_1_to_999 = RemoveTrailingZero<Values<{
    [P in Values<MakeSet<LiteralDigits>>]: AppendDigit<P>
}>>

type By<V extends NumberString<number>> = RemoveTrailingZero<Values<{
    [P in V]: AppendDigit<P>
}>>

type From_1_to_99999 =
    | From_1_to_999
    | By<From_1_to_999>
    | By<From_1_to_999
        | By<From_1_to_999>>
```

[Demo](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAaghgGwK4QM4B4AqA%20KBeKTAbQGsIQB7AM0IF0Aoe0SKAGQEtgIAnRAEXYBzTqnxQADFAA%20UAIzSoAJgUBmBQBYFAVgUA2BQHYFADgUBOJuGgA5JAFsARjwDKwbuwB2grFAgAPLg8AE1EPeyduXAIAAwASAG9MAF9oxmZoAEEwSGCBYWAff0CQqDDHHgVUN09BKKg4xKSEji5eBDyRFLSrKABZODJnCALMXwCIYNDwnjr4%20igFqCIABShPOgAuKCycoI6C5ex6JO6WACUIOwoANwhMXnYEGoAtHgpC8cmoKvcvOtGihMSg1PFQKgAxKpNeKgioXKHRKAAfigkOAY2Komi4kRKIuV1u9zgjxeb3QDXhwBSuC2DTR0MpKSgWw8EFu3AA3KdoODuBQ7AB9WQC4AUAVmCVifE3O4PJ5eV589DwZBodBzRZLVbrFUoDD9QbDdAtHj8IQibDYWhbHZA-boQ7HS3cqAAIRAyoxQNEtnK3Fcv28ZQilqllxlRJJCrJurVGsWKzWHlg1u22Tt5oORySzssLF5-KFIrFEtL%20HmixkBcFwtF4olFYWMnd6GrRbrpaOmubHrbtZLDc13bdvb5NeL9bMuaAA)

**UPDATE 3**

If you still want to generate literal numbers, not string numbers, you can use this code, which has been shamelessly stolen from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39494689/is-it-possible-to-restrict-number-to-a-certain-range)

```js
type PrependNextNum<A extends Array<unknown>> = A['length'] extends infer T ? ((t: T, ...a: A) => void) extends ((...x: infer X) => void) ? X : never : never;

type EnumerateInternal<A extends Array<unknown>, N extends number> = { 0: A, 1: EnumerateInternal<PrependNextNum<A>, N> }[N extends A['length'] ? 0 : 1];

type Enumerate<N extends number> = EnumerateInternal<[], N> extends (infer E)[] ? E : never;

type Result = Enumerate<43> // 0 | 1 | 2 | ... | 42
```

**UPDATE 8 September 2021*

Since TS 4.5, see [Tail recursion PR](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/45711), it is possible to generate much longer number range.

See example:

```js
type MAXIMUM_ALLOWED_BOUNDARY = 999

type ComputeRange<
    N extends number,
    Result extends Array<unknown> = [],
    > =
    (Result['length'] extends N
        ? Result
        : ComputeRange<N, [...Result, Result['length']]>
    )

const ComputeRange = (N: number, Result: number[] = []): number[] => {
    if (Result.length === N) {
        return Result
    }
    return ComputeRange(N, [...Result, Result.length])
}
// 0 , 1, 2 ... 998
type NumberRange = ComputeRange<MAXIMUM_ALLOWED_BOUNDARY>[number]
```

[Related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69089549/typescript-template-literal-type-how-to-infer-numeric-type/69090186?noredirect=1#comment122137982_69090186)

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.5.0-dev.20210908#code/C4TwDgpgBAsgggDQJIwKowPpwDLYPIDqAogCIYBCeqAciXAEoCaUAvFACwCcArALABQA0JCgBhAPYBbMAFdgEegEMAdgHMIAHgFQdUalAgAPecoAmAZyjKZkgEYQATgBptu%20hHMyANsAPGIZpZwDg6KIBoyygDWyuIA7soAfKxQANoAui78ulDJLK46ABTunj6pAOReAarAABbl6X4mFnoFOVAA-FAl3sBtOQBcYlKy8kpqmtROaQB0cz0%200wvAFVVqdQ3piW0AlAICAMbiyua%20EtJyCirqKYXUQ9Z2jksevQ829g4ZKRk7709fRosZIAbzaAEsAGZQYqvHwzNY1WqsFhsag7KBg7LtHQOCDAGQOZTdOF9bE6AC%20bTxBKJwwuY2uEDu01ScxmyxepWACOqdXSe34VP4AHoRVAAAxQaYARmmACYoOyOJx2EJwNBqB9HOMbmxzqMrhMNPBkGhMDh8MQyJQaHQmIlUo9Pul9oJ3UA)

Comment: I'm trying to figure out how to make it for double number, for example: 10|11|12|13 ....

Comment: You can do it like [this](https://tsplay.dev/zwOYMm) but I'm not sure if that matches the use case or not.  If the OP cares about gaps or wants an unbounded maximum size then it becomes hairier

Comment: There's also `data-element-${number}`, but that accepts non-whole number values.  The upside is there's no built-in maximum value or huge union type.