# Add an string to each tuple

Tags: typescript, tuples

I have an type

`type mytype = 'tipe-1' | 'tipe-2' | 'tipe-3'`

how to type like this
`type mytype2 = '1' | '2' | '3'`

but the output still the same `'tipe-1' | 'tipe-2' | 'tipe-3'`

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: If you want to generate more numbers, check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65307438/how-to-define-properties-in-a-typescript-interface-with-dynamic-elements-in-the

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Template Literal Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html) for this:

```
type MyType = `tipe-${1 | 2 | 3}`
```

This is identical to:

```
type MyType = 'tipe-1' | 'tipe-2' | 'tipe-3'
```

You can abstract this if you'd like to use it in multiple places:

```
type MakeMyType<T extends number> = `tipe-${T}`;

type MyType = MakeMyType<1 | 2 | 3>;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this is what i need