# infer template string return unexpected infer result

Tags: typescript

I was thinking the following `Y` will return `test`, however, it returns `never`, anyone has any idea the reason why and potential solution?

```
type X<T> = T extends `${infer U}.${number}` ? U : never
type Y = X<`test.${number}`>; // expect "test" but got never
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.3.0-dev.20210228#code/C4TwDgpgBAGgPAFQHxQLxQVCAPYEB2AJgM5QAGAJAN4CW%20AZhAE5QCqAvgHTX4CuAtgCNm7MlAD8bKAC4o%20CADdmAKFCQoATTSw4ZPMWDcqfISLJIA3FAD01rNkgBjYFABE%204K6hA)

Comment: I think it is design limitation. Here you have TS PR https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/40336
Can't find there such feature

Comment: it works with X<`test.5`>

Comment: thanks @captain-yossarian yea, just infer is not working for the string part.

Answer (score 1):

Taken from [template literals PR](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/40336)

> Any one of the types any, string, number, boolean, or bigint in a placeholder causes the template literal to resolve to type string.

This code works as expected:

```js
type X<T> = T extends `test.${infer A}` ? A : never;

type Z = X<`test.${number}`>; // string
type Z1 = X<`test.${bigint}`>; // string
type Z2 = X<`test.${boolean}`>; // "false" | "true"
```

However, this code works as you expect:

```js
type X<T> = T extends `${infer B}.${infer A}` ? B : never;

type Z = X<`test.${boolean}`>; // "test"
```

Why it works with `boolean`? Because boolean is a union type "true | false" under the hood.

So, this should work:

```js
type Z = X<`test.${1|2|3|4|5}`>; // test
```

If we already know that it works with union types, I think we can generate some union of numbers.

Taken from my [blog](https://catchts.com/range-numbers), [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65307438/how-to-define-properties-in-a-typescript-interface-with-dynamic-elements-in-the):

```js
type Values<T> = T[keyof T];

type LiteralDigits = 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9;

type NumberString<T extends number> = `${T}`

type AppendDigit<T extends number | string> = `${T}${LiteralDigits}`


type MakeSet<T extends number> = {
  [P in T]: AppendDigit<P>;
};

type RemoveTrailingZero<
  T extends string
> = T extends `${infer Fst}${infer Rest}`
  ? Fst extends `0`
    ? RemoveTrailingZero<Rest>
    : `${Fst}${Rest}`
  : never;

type From_1_to_999 = RemoveTrailingZero<
  Values<
    {
      [P in Values<MakeSet<LiteralDigits>>]: AppendDigit<P>;
    }
  >
>;

type By<V extends NumberString<number>> = RemoveTrailingZero<
  Values<
    {
      [P in V]: AppendDigit<P>;
    }
  >
>;

/**
 * Did not use recursion here,
 * because my CPU will blow up
 */
type From_1_to_99999 =
  | From_1_to_999
  | By<From_1_to_999>
  | By<From_1_to_999 | By<From_1_to_999>>;

type X<T extends string> = T extends `${infer B}.${infer A}` ? B : never

type Z = X<`test.${From_1_to_99999}`>; // test
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAaghgGwK4QM4B4AqA%20KBeKTAbQGsIQB7AM0IF0BuAWACgXRIoAZAS2AgCdEAEW4BzXqnxQADFAA%20UAIzyoAJhUBmFQBYVAVhUA2FQHYVADhUBOJq2btoAOSQBbAEYCAysH7cAdqJYUBAAHnx%20ACaSfq4e-LgEAAYAJADemAC%20iSxs4NAAgmCQkSLiwEGh4VFQMe4CKqg%20-qIJUCnpGWk8fIIIpRJZOXYOUACycGSeEOWYwWEQkdGxAq2pLFBQRAAKUP50AFxQhcUR-eVb2LYZtrkcAEoQLhQAbhCYgtwIzQBaAhTo60IcyqkkavgCLFas0qC2q7X8VHqADFGp1Ugj6g9UdlmBsAPxQFHAYGwySJaQ4jb4qAPJ6vd5wT4-P7oLHAbCAjaHdpEtFswa4qCHPwQV78G72PKE-gUFwAfUUcuAFDlVjVUlpLzeHy%20AV%20MoBgvgyDQhqpUDWgvN212flgiBQGHGk2m6G6AmEYgk2GwtEOx1hZ3QF1s5oygI5zEuQxGACEQOgYCTFlBnHV%20N5wYFanEfRrHlqGUy9SzAcbHWaqZbzRsbXsYH6jkVA17ztGrVBw4LI%202WAB6ABUA-WA6gIgiNQoxKQqGg-AgAGMkPxUNwKHaABYCCAAGhHUA8C7gM%20gLhAUAAwlsAKpQADunwQB4QFDvUCQYBHfdu0CRMvlirKqqarqnggIKH%20soKkqKogeBUDxugkEATBwFWJGGwKIhyHQUBIEqNh-64bBao%20hKIwABoVPMKZgs0ULJnCaQYvwCEZAAdMxfiIqx%20RZFABKxkKNSigIMZSt8UhUYkfCNJxqQ4YBJEgVklxQH2fZQLJwBAA)

There is another one solution, not so expensive for CPU, but with own limitations:

```js
type PrependNextNum<A extends Array<unknown>> = A["length"] extends infer T
  ? ((t: T, ...a: A) => void) extends (...x: infer X) => void
    ? X
    : never
  : never;

type EnumerateInternal<A extends Array<unknown>, N extends number> = {
  0: A;
  1: EnumerateInternal<PrependNextNum<A>, N>;
}[N extends A["length"] ? 0 : 1];

type Enumerate<N extends number> = EnumerateInternal<[], N> extends (infer E)[]
  ? E
  : never;

// Up to 42 - meaning of the life
type Result = Enumerate<43>; // 0 | 1 | 2 | ... | 42

type X<T extends string> = T extends `${infer B}.${infer A}` ? B : never

type Z = X<`test.${Result}`>; // test
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBACgThSA7AJgOQgD2GgrgWwB4BBKLYCVAZymLjgEMRDckBrJAewHckA%20PlAC8tANoAiADaUA5sAAW4gLplslFDQCWSAGYQ4UACoBYAFBQoAfigAKG8ABcRgDRQAdB4ZPiASmGCAN05NFD9ydRobDzdMJ209AwANPyFA4JQzCwtrRMyspyQIAP08gqL9AG4zM1BIKABRJAJ9BgoASSQKOCQGSRJVCmpaeiYWdi5ePlc0AYioJvwAI31BEQBvPIAGbyrzKABGJ0bmxnbO-R6%20%20ER1DGw8ImIpqDQ%20XYBfURnwoeIJaSQckUKmsmygTn2Sl2NXA0GO%20BaFEI3zUQwWyzgqwaC0REA6XUuhFESmmgh%20Gls8X0DR8xLy1nqpXm5Tg0NMAHp2VAAKpgKDAThQAAsACYoABaKAIhhIbQyKCcHT8%20TQSSaPQwuoAJQgVFwkmAwmxJ1aEEIQoAzG8oJyoGCAD4HKCOsWO6LO4UioA)

SO it is up to you which solution is better for you.