# Typescript Can we compose object key types from string and number

Tags: typescript

I have the following interface:

```
interface AdvancedFilterState {
  customAttributesName1?: manualInputType,
  customAttributesValue1?: manualInputType,
  customAttributesName2?: manualInputType,
  customAttributesValue2?: manualInputType,

  ...and this can go forever
}
```

I want to have a key patter that matches `customAttributesName` and a number and `customAttributesValue` and a number.

To get this pass I use a way to generic patter like this

```
interface AdvancedFilterState {
  [key: string]: someType
}
```

can I do something like

```
type keytype = 'customAttributesName' + number;
interface AdvancedFilterState {
  [key: keytype]: someType
}
```

How to solve this in typescript?

Comment: Yes, you can. [Example](https://tsplay.dev/w244rm)

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65307438/how-to-define-properties-in-a-typescript-interface-with-dynamic-elements-in-the/65307734#65307734) question might be a duplicate, I'm not sure

Comment: This is not working for me. I get the following error:
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'AdvancedFilterState'.
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'AdvancedFilterState'.ts(7053)

Comment: please provide an example with error you are getting