# Clamped number type in typescript

Tags: typescript, types, annotations

I've an interface like this:

```js
interface Angle{
    value: number
}
```

And i was wondering if there's an elegant way to convert `number` to something like `ClampedNumber<min, max>` with two numbers instead of `min` and `max`

Comment: THis answer is not stricly related to your question but still can be helpful https://catchts.com/range-numbers

Answer (score 1):

Technically, you can make a generic type that would result in a union of
`min | min + 1 | ... | max - 1| max`

([Is it possible to restrict number to a certain range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39494689/is-it-possible-to-restrict-number-to-a-certain-range)).

But not only it seems like a complex and not so performance friendly idea.
I would not recommend it because you would need to use casting a lot.