# Typescript: declare type of index of tuple?

Tags: typescript

Given a TypeScript Tuple e.g.:

```js
const arr = [1, 2] as const;
```

We get static type checks on indexing:

```js
console.log(arr[1]);
```

is good, but

```js
console.log(arr[2]);
```

errors with:

> Tuple type 'readonly [1, 2]' of length '2' has no element at index '2'.ts (2493)

which is great.

---

I'd like to declare a constant to be of the type of the index of that tuple, so that what can be assigned to that constant follows the same constraints (`0 | 1`).

I tried this:

```js
const index: keyof typeof arr = 2 as const;
console.log(arr[index]);
```

but TypeScript didn't show any errors. I suspect that `index` is a `number` which is too broad.

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/werRaN) meet your needs? If so I can write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz yes, looks about right

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yeah, for whatever reason, tuple indices are numeric string [literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) like `"0"` and `"1"` instead of the corresponding *numeric* literal types like `0` and `1`.  There's also a `number` [index signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures), so `keyof ["a", "b"]` will give you `number | "0" | "1" | ...`.  Which means just using `keyof` will let you assign any number whatsoever.

If you want to compute the numeric literals, you can use [template literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#template-literal-types) to do so, at least in TypeScript 4.8 and above:

```
type TupleIndices<T extends readonly any[]> =
    Extract<keyof T, `${number}`> extends `${infer N extends number}` ? N : never;
```

First I [`Extract`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#extracttype-union) the numeric string literal types from the full key set by filtering on `` `${number}` ``, the set of all strings that can be parsed as a number.  This eliminates `number` itself (which isn't a string) and also `"length"` and `"slice"` and other array members.  So that gives us `"0" | "1" | "2" | ...`.  Then I use [the improved `infer` types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-8.html#improved-inference-for-infer-types-in-template-string-types) introduced in TypeScript 4.8 to convert those string literals to numeric literals.

That gives you this:

```
const arr = [1, 2] as const;

type ArrIndices = TupleIndices<typeof arr>;
// type ArrIndices = 0 | 1

type Also = TupleIndices<[9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9]>;
// type Also = 0 | 1 | 2 | 9 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhgJwTAvDA2gRgDQwEwC68EMokUA3AFBVQCeADgKYwAqArgwDZMCSYAEwCWwJhAA8rGEwAeUJoJIImcAeC514YOugIA+VFRjGYAUTkI4wKOIDWTOiABmbXAAMAJAG8w7ALYARkwIAL5uBrLyijCeXkJgTsEwAHLScgoCJL6BwWEwAPwpMABcMGBMAG7B1LSMLACCSPzCoiRoHNx8giJi4vTMzvBIetQA9KMw-Q1N3a2oMAAMMAA+MJg0tcww9VwQIPMdPM09EugAnLgXMFc3l3fX92f6YxNT27v7aEurmCv4f2c-gBmP4AFj+AFY-gA2P4Adj+AA4gA)

Answer (score 1):

A bit of a hack, based on [tail-recursively defining a range of numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70307091/6517320):

```js
type Enumerate<
    N extends number,
    Acc extends number[] = [],
> = Acc['length'] extends N
    ? Acc[number]
    : Enumerate<N, [...Acc, Acc['length']]>;
type Range<F extends number, T extends number> = Exclude<
    Enumerate<T>,
    Enumerate<F>
>;

const index: Range<0, typeof arr['length']> = 2 as const;
// Type '2' is not assignable to type '0 | 1'. ts(2322)
```

Comment: Yeah, I was trying to come up with that approach too. Then jcalz posted [their comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73919926/typescript-declare-type-of-index-of-tuple#comment130520512_73919926) and I just went "well, I mean, if you want to do it the *easy* way..." :-)

Comment: If you are using TS4.7 or below this is more or less the only way, since only TS4.8 introduced [a way of converting string literal types to numeric literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-8.html#improved-inference-for-infer-types-in-template-string-types).