# Return a Type error if prop passed is out of range

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a component which takes in two props; children(react elements) and index.
When index is passed, it should return the child element at that particular index.
I would like to modify my types to return a type error incase the index passed is out of range ie if I have a total of 6 elements and index passed is 40. I would like typescript to showing me that I cannot input that index.... in the Main component.

```
import React from 'react';
type IComp = {
    children: React.ReactElement[],
    index: number
}

function Comp(props: IComp) {
    return (
        <div >
            {props.children.map((item) => {
                return (
                    <button></button>
                )
            })}
        </div>
    )
}

function Main() {
    return (
        <Comp index={20}>
            <div>
                <p>One</p>
            </div>
            <div >
                <p>Two</p>
            </div>
            <div>
                <p>Three</p>
            </div>
        </Comp >
    );
}
```

Comment: Does this help? [Is it possible to restrict number to a certain range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39494689/is-it-possible-to-restrict-number-to-a-certain-range)

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/Wkkz9W) meet your needs? If so, I will write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?  (Pls mention @jcalz if you reply to notify me)

Comment: @jcalz, this approach works, and I have edited the question a bit.

Comment: I'm not thrilled that the scope of the question has expanded in response to a suggested answer that worked for the original version.  Could you please undo that edit so I can answer the question you asked? If you need to expand the scope after that, you could post a new question asking it.  Let me know (@jcalz to notify me)

Comment: @jcalz, I have rolled back to the original question.

Comment: Okay, I'll write up an answer.  You might want to fix the typos in your code here, right now there are syntax issues.  [This](https://tsplay.dev/NdrJnW) seems to be the minimum edits necessary to get your original code to be a [mre].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order for this to work, your `Comp` component needs to keep track of the exact length of the `children` array, so that it can compare `index` to it.  That means the `children` component will need to be something like a [tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types) instead of an arbitrary array type, and `IComp` will need to be [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) in that tuple type.

Here's one approach:

```
type IComp<T extends React.ReactElement[]> = {
    children: [...T],
    index: StrToNum<`${number}` & keyof T>
}

type StrToNum<T> = T extends `${infer N extends number}` ? N : never
```

So `children` is of generic type `T` which is [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) to `ReactElement[]`.  Actually it's the [variadic tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-0.html#variadic-tuple-types) `[...T]`, which is essentially the same as `T` except it gives the compiler a hint that it should infer a tuple type instead of just an array type when it sees an array in that position.

And `index` is going to be a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of all the applicable numeric [literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) corresponding to valid indices of the `T` tuple.  First, if you inspect `keyof T` (using [the `keyof` type operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/keyof-types.html#the-keyof-type-operator)) where `T` is a tuple, you'll see a bunch of array method member names, plus string versions of the valid numeric indices:

```
type ExampleTuple = [Element, Element, Element];

type ExampleTupleKeys = keyof ExampleTuple;
/* type ExampleTupleKeys = number | typeof Symbol.iterator | typeof Symbol.unscopables | 
  "0" | "1" | "2" | 
  "length" | "toString" | "toLocaleString" | "pop" | "push" | 
  "concat" | "join" | "reverse" | "shift" | 
  "slice" | "sort" | "splice" | "unshift" | "indexOf" | 
  "lastIndexOf" | "every" | "some" | "forEach" | 
  "map" | "filter" | "reduce" | "reduceRight" | "find" | 
  "findIndex" | "fill" | "copyWithin" | 
  "entries" | "keys" | "values" | "includes" */
```

That `"0" | "1" | "2"` is the part we care about.  To get rid of everything else, we can [intersect](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) those keys with `` `${number}` ``, a [template literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html) roughly corresponding to "all numeric strings" ([more or less](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/41893#issuecomment-886951161)):

```
type NumericStringExampleTupleKeys = keyof ExampleTuple & `${number}`
// type NumericStringExampleTupleKeys = "0" | "1" | "2"
```

So this is closer to what we want, but you don't want to use strings like `"1"`, you want numbers like `1`.  Which means we need to convert string literal types to number literal types.  This can now be done directly with [TypeScript 4.8's improved inference in template literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-8.html#improved-inference-for-infer-types-in-template-string-types), allowing us to write the `StrToNum<T>` utility type above:

```
type NumericExampleTupleKeys = StrToNum<keyof ExampleTuple & `${number}`>;
// type NumericExampleTupleKeys = 0 | 1 | 2
```

And there you go, the set of acceptable numeric indices to `T`.

---

So you want `Comp` to be generic in `T` just like `IComp`:

```
function Comp<T extends React.ReactElement[]>(props: IComp<T>): JSX.Element {
  /* impl */
}
```

And now we can test it:

```
// okay
<Comp index={2}>
    <div><p>One</p></div><div><p>Two</p></div>
    <div><p>Three</p></div>
</Comp >

// error! Type '3' is not assignable to type '0 | 1 | 2'
<Comp index={3}>
    <div><p>One</p></div><div><p>Two</p></div>
    <div><p>Three</p></div>
</Comp >

// okay
<Comp index={3}>
    <div><p>One</p></div><div><p>Two</p></div>
    <div><p>Three</p></div><div><p>Four</p></div>
</Comp >
```

The compiler detects that `2` is a valid index when `Comp` has three children, and that `3` is an invalid index when `Comp` has three children, but a valid index when `Comp` has four.  Looks good!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=4&noErrorTruncation=true#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wG4BYAKCqpgE8wk4BJAYVzAB4AVOJADxhIAdgBMAzomIwAdMnQwAogBskIETADaAXQB8cALxwA3lTjm4aABbBloosIBccTTLfdtAGjMXgYgc4AyjBQ3BAAcgCuIJwABgAkxsLRAEZIUAC+sXAAZHAA1kh0EJhw3LpUGTSU9IxwwaER0Tz6RrwCQmKSCcZ+mOlw4XyCIhJwySBpmdkA-INwzsJIAG7p1bVMivwo4KrckWCqhi4qahqecKfqwjAXVxraFNQ1DJvbu0j7h0gA0kWSRkKxVKWx23y+qieAHoAFRwDaXd7gg6qP50AHjVIDAA+8NeJXqdEmEGUMmAQigKBg0DguI2BMCRJSJJkkWE4jQEDAKBSqkkuIARAAGAW0uACgCMosFACZpXAfALVMIAOYwKzygXUhp+FWa6kAGQgaBQqh1qs1kDAlsi4g1YoFnOEJpgmoAVhA-JqiKsoOIkJq7cBMK6xYrxMpgGgAw7xNBQ4LxIcozHBWygyHNX5RAIAPKYTXKFDiGDMfz8fOalbpOiB3Cp8WYaCKdD23GKkAoa0OzC2CnepCiSLRgdD6MIYAqqwJxvZzW9sRlnP8ee2ZSazlgOgAdXJNmE8sVGigwCQ4k1QPPDuWpsiZ6zzuUkRzV5hUPWr0G0XSUfNKtBHwQr8-zHECBIAci3y5HAPQTFMWRUFCUJ4nUUTqCeaB-hBewosB6LHMKmpSg6cofqh34Ydhny4WiGINGEaGcGBIJIjhUF5LBWLTLo0LIQiaE-mgVFAbRxxCmKEpijK1SYGyGDABAwhwOw4A8MMnRjPIGByNI9w3DougABRgDgYDiM4bAcC0ACUzgAFKBAAGjIenwKYlAWHARAwJEUBKYZPieeYnCiMAyz6EFkXGCZXLiDI1i2PYIgyJ2YCGYZ5JqNZhj6O5kWRd5vn+YF+WRZwKSRDA1LCLonBQhVVWKRUHmlRY1klZ5GTWVULVlVCoXhSV7WUD1VCyc6MAKUpACyKB+IZ2V5RYIVhc1pVIXAED5CgdAdctKlgHA2YCAYxgyhka2tcFA21WAui5ksdV3XVN0reFnB3dwADuEBPbV-WrXtZWvZ9VhEEgf0vYDvVBXVB1wJdkUbekOBQAAhGUn74AAzPgR2SMIEDwMW4iTsIPJHNSKFMPg4m4pJuIyvgQNwJw8PHfwp3YxdLOeW9t33Y9ULPQD70g7o32-cL-03bzy3i9wYNIBD0tQ4NMN81C8OI0FG1bTtLNsxwR3llzPMa-l-MfYLKsi69Cs-ZDos66VVug+DTv26t1sAGIQL5nvQ67WvGzravNRkQA)