# Constraint typedef to range of integer in Dart

Tags: dart

Can I constraint a typedef to range of integers in Dart?

Like shown in this TypeScript SO [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39494689/is-it-possible-to-restrict-number-to-a-certain-range)

```
type MyRange = 5|6|7|8|9|10

let myVar:MyRange = 4; // oops, error :)
```

I would like to limit:

```
Dice dice = 0; // warning not compile
Dice dice = 1;
Dice dice = 2;
Dice dice = 3;
Dice dice = 4;
Dice dice = 5;
Dice dice = 6;
Dice dice = 7; // warning not compile
```

Like:

```
typedef Dice = 1|2|3|4|5|6
```

Is it possible in Dart somehow?

Comment: Not possible in Dart. I would suggest using an `enum` instead of if you want to limit a variable to a limited set of values.

Comment: Dart does not literally support this, but it can be done using a suitable class.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a class that takes a set of allowed values and throws and exception if a value not in the set is assigned to its `value` member:

```
class Restricted<T> {
  late final Set<T> _validSet;

  late T _value;

  Restricted(Set<T> validSet) {
    _validSet = Set<T>.unmodifiable(validSet);
  }

  T get value => _value;

  set value(T newValue) {
    if (!_validSet.contains(newValue)) {
      throw RangeError('$newValue is not a valid value');
    }

    _value = newValue;
  }
}
```

And use it like

```
var r = Restricted<int>({1,2,3,4,5,6});

r.value = 2;  // Okay
r.value = 0;  // throws ValueError
```

See the code in action on [DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/32d15f84430153913c2153335edaf041)

Comment: That's in runtime. But I hoped to get IDE warnings and not able to compile

Comment: @lolelo For compile time, use an Enum class.

Comment: Do you mean the generic `T` as enum, or the class `Restricted` could be Enum?

Comment: @lolelo I mean to use an  `Enum` the way it is intended to be used: A value from a fixed set of options. Since Dart does not support restricted scalar (int) types, this may the the solution you need. It even offers the benefit of having named, printable values. Check it out: https://api.dart.dev/be/180791/dart-core/Enum-class.html

Comment: It could be restricting values to certain string values, like names. or only allowing certain double values, like person weights in certain values, person length to be 1.10, 1.20, 1.30.... Yes in Dart it seems to be limited to Enum in this.
It's a language based feature question. In the question my code example is a example.

Answer (score 0):

You are asking about a possible solution you have in mind, without sharing the actual problem.

If you state you real problem in more general terms, you may find a better answer here. Maybe an [`Enum`](https://api.dart.dev/be/180791/dart-core/Enum-class.html) is a better fit than a restricted `int`.