# Is it possible to generate a union type of numbers without explicitly stating each one?

Tags: typescript

Say I wanted to generate a union type of numbers that go up by a scale, but the amount of entries in the union will be quite large, could I generate that without explicitly typing out every type in the union?

Say I have `type ScaleByEight = 8 | 16 | 24 | 32 ... 400;`

Could I create a utility that where I can pass a min, max and value to scale by?

Something like `type ScaleByEight = ScaleBy</* min */ 8, /* max */, 400, /* scale by */ 8>;`

Comment: You can check [my article](https://catchts.com/range-numbers) about generation number range or my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69089549/typescript-template-literal-type-how-to-infer-numeric-type#answer-69090186)

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/NlL6XN) meet your needs? If so I could write up an answer (although I'm sure it's similar in spirit to @captain-yossarianfromUkraine's). If not what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz please write an answer. Always learn smth new from you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible, however I would not rely on this logic too much on PROD code:

```js
type MAXIMUM_ALLOWED_BOUNDARY = 999

type ComputeRange<
    N extends number,
    Result extends Array<unknown> = [],
> =
    (Result['length'] extends N
        ? Result
        : ComputeRange<N, [...Result, Result['length']]>
    )

type Add<A extends number, B extends number> = [...ComputeRange<A>, ...ComputeRange<B>]['length']

type IsGreater<A extends number, B extends number> = IsLiteralNumber<[...ComputeRange<B>][Last<[...ComputeRange<A>]>]> extends true ? false : true

type Last<T extends any[]> = T extends [...infer _, infer Last] ? Last extends number ? Last : never : never

type RemoveLast<T extends any[]> = T extends [...infer Rest, infer _] ? Rest : never

type IsLiteralNumber<N> = N extends number ? number extends N ? false : true : false


type AddIteration<Min extends number, Max extends number, ScaleBy extends number, Result extends Array<unknown> = [Min]> =
    IsGreater<Last<Result>, Max> extends true
    ? RemoveLast<Result>
    : AddIteration<
        Min, Max, ScaleBy, [...Result, Add<Last<Result>, ScaleBy>]
    >

// [5, 13, 21, 29, 37]
type Result = AddIteration<5, 40, 8>
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/w6L7Gm)

Please see my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69089549/typescript-template-literal-type-how-to-infer-numeric-type#answer-69090186) and [article](https://catchts.com/range-numbers)

Explanation for `ComputeRange` you can find in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69089549/typescript-template-literal-type-how-to-infer-numeric-type#answer-69090186) answer and [my article](https://catchts.com/range-numbers)

`Add` - just concatenates two arrays and returns new length. Just like :

```js
const add=(xl:number[], yl:number[]) => [...xl,...yl].length
```

`IsLiteralNumbe` - checks whether provided number is literal number like `2` or `42` or just a general type of `number`.

`Last` returns last element of an array

`IsGreater` checks whether last element of `ComputeRange<A>` can be used as an index for `ComputeRangeB`. Please keep in mind that all elements in `ComputedRange` are also indexes.

`AddIteration` - is a recursive utility type, which checks whether last element of Result is greater then Max. If yes - return Result without last element otherwise, call itself recursively with addition.

Here you can test js representation. I made it as close as I could, but not everything can be expressed.

```js
const add = (a: number, b: number) => [...computeRange(a), ...computeRange(b)]['length']

const isLiteralNumber = (value: any) => typeof value === 'number'

const last = (xl: number[]) => {
    //const [...rest, last] = xl
    return xl[xl.length - 1]
}

const computeRange = (n: number) => Array(n).fill(0).map((_, index) => index)

const isGreater = (a: number, b: number) => isLiteralNumber([...computeRange(b)][last(computeRange(a))]) ? false : true

const addIteration = (min: number, max: number, scaleBy: number, result = [min]): number[] => {
    if (isGreater(last(result), max)) {
        return result
    }

    return addIteration(min, max, scaleBy, [...result, add(last(result), scaleBy)])
}
const result = addIteration(5, 40, 8)

// [ 5, 13, 21, 29, 37, 45 ]
console.log({ result })
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no `Range` type at the moment.

It's an [open issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15480) on GitHub.